# How does performance compare getting a tibble row by index, then getting the column value; to getting the column, then getting the value by index?

Tags: r, tidyverse

How does the performance of these two ways of getting the single value from a tibble using a row index and a column name compare?

```
library(tidyverse) # or minimally, `library(tibble)`

# 10000 rows and 50 columns of random values
tibble_text <- paste0(
  "tibble(",
  paste0("\'col", 1:50, "\' = rnorm(10000)", collapse = ", "),
  ")")

my_tibble <- eval(parse(text = tibble_text))
```

Getting the row, then the value:

```
i <- 542
my_tibble[i,]$col18
```

Getting the column, then the value:

```
i <- 542
my_tibble$col18[i]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Retrieving the column first (`my_tibble$col18[i]`) is much faster:

```
# I chose to randomize the column index, in case
# something sneaky was happening under the hood.

{
  ptm <- proc.time()
  for (i in 1:10000) {
    eval(parse(text=paste0("my_tibble[i,]$col", sample(1:50, 1))))
  }
  proc.time() - ptm
}

# user  system elapsed 
# 2.53    0.00    2.52 


{
  ptm <- proc.time()
  for (i in 1:10000) {
    eval(parse(text=paste0("my_tibble$col", sample(1:50, 1), "[i]")))
  }
  proc.time() - ptm
}

# user  system elapsed 
# 0.33    0.00    0.33
```

I think the main reason for this is that a tibble is built not as a matrix, but as an object that contains columns. When getting the row first, you are getting a tibble object with 50 columns of length 1 and then asking for the value of the chosen column. When you do it the other way, it gets the column, which is already basically just a named vector, and then the ith value of it.